# Control Ubuntu from Windows over Bluetooth

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, 14.10, remote-desktop

Do you know of any software that allows to open the Ubuntu terminal from Windows over Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know over bluetooth, but you can do it if you are in the same Lan, via ssh or xrdp =)

**ssh:**

`sudo apt-get install opensshserver` <- ubuntu

Download putty.exe <- windows

**xrdp**

`sudo apt-get install rdesktop (or freerdp-x11)` <- ubuntu

remote desktop for windows is installed by default

I hope this could help you mate.

Answer (score 0):

That will be a combination of

1. setting up a Bluetooth network ([for Ubuntu](//help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup); for Windows you'd better ask on [SuperUser](//superuser.com/) as it would be off topic here and most people here don't know that much about Windows) and
2. then an SSH server on Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   ```

The two are pretty unrelated as SSH will work over any TCP/IP network once you have it running, so please open a new question for either of the two if you encounter any issues.